# No pool was specified Error shows up for the migrated builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We have recently migrated few of our builds to a different Azure DevOps Environment using Azure DevOps migration tool. The build pipelines are pointing to the microsoft hosted agents but they are failing due to issue

> No pool was specified

A newly created build works fine with the same build configuration. Attached screenshots contain sample yamls that are exactly the same, however the migrated build fails with the error and the newly created build works fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Pools specified in `azure-pipelines.yml` don't actually seem to be used by Azure;  instead, you have to set it via the GUI.

From the pipeline editor:

1. Click on the button with the three dots at the top-right.
2. Click on "Triggers".
3. Click on "YAML", which is a tab to the top-left.
4. Select a default agent pool.

That's it!  Just save & queue your pipeline, and it should run without issue.

Comment: Consider going to this issue on the feedback hub and commenting on the "solution" to let Microsoft know we'd like this fixed. We shouldn't have to do a workaround.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Auto-created-pipeline-from-yaml-return-e/10054547?q=yaml+no+pool+was+specified